# When passing a uri with metadata created by infura ipfs or pinata ipfs from a react app to NFT contract I receive this Error: invalid BigNumber string

Tags: solidity, javascript, ethers.js, etherscan, goerli

For testing purposes I have "downsized" my original NFT contract, to a very basic one, to understand where this error is coming from. When I call the mint function I need to pass an uri. It seems as though the contract does not accept the format I am passing, but I don't understand why and which format it needs.

The whole error message in the browser: error:

```
Error: invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/Qm....", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.7.0)
```

**my contract:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";

contract NFT is ERC721URIStorage {
    uint public tokenCount;
    constructor() ERC721("NFT", "token"){}
    function mint(string memory _tokenURI) external returns(uint) {
        tokenCount ++;
        _safeMint(msg.sender, tokenCount);
        _setTokenURI(tokenCount, _tokenURI);
        return(tokenCount);
    }
```

Comment: Check if the ABI is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "invalid BigNumber string" is indicating that the value you're passing as the token ID is not a valid BigNumber string. The token ID is the first argument to the _safeMint function and _setTokenURI function.

In this case, it appears that the token ID is being generated as tokenCount and being incremented with each call to the mint function. If tokenCount is a uint type, it should be valid as a BigNumber string.

It's possible that the error is coming from the _tokenURI argument. The _setTokenURI function expects a string for the token URI, and it's possible that the URI string you're passing is not being stored properly in the contract.

Make sure that the string you're passing as the _tokenURI argument is a valid IPFS hash and that it's being properly stored in the contract. You may want to check the contract storage to see if the string is being stored correctly.

Additionally, you can try converting the URI to a different format (e.g. hexadecimal) before passing it to the mint function and see if that resolves the issue.